# JavaMelody aggregate monitoring report for multi ageing server

Tags: rest, spring-boot, java-11

I have configured JavaMelody in my application and its working fine with one instance and returning all the required graph and stats when I hit **{domain-url}/monitoring** but actual problem comes when I deployed my application on multi ageing environment(AWS EC2 load balancer) and suppose if I have 3 (server Ips: **10.45.120.10, 10.45.120.11 and 10.45.120.103**) instance there then when I call **{domain-url}/monitoring** it shows once instance(server Ip **10.45.120.10**) stats and graphs and when I re-hit **{domain-url}/monitoring** it display another instance(Server Ip **10.45.120.11**) stats and graphs and so on.

Is there any way to view aggregate stats and graphs from all instance in one page on one hit **{domain-url}/monitoring**

Javamelody dependencies is below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
    <artifactId>javamelody-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.81.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and my **application.properties** for javamelody

```
javamelody.enabled=true
javamelody.init-parameters.log=true
javamelody.spring-monitoring-enabled=true
javamelody.init-parameters.url-exclude-pattern=(/webjars/.*)
javamelody.init-parameters.authorized-users= user:mypass
javamelody.init-parameters.monitoring-path= /monitoring
javamelody.obsolete-graphs-days=60
javamelody.obsolete-stats-days=60
```

**Note:** when I am using javamelody.init-parameters.storage-directory=/opt/myapp then no stats is displaying

P.S. I am using maven spring boot 2.1.1, Java11, javamelody 1.81.0 and my application is restful only.

Comment: You would need an additional application to aggregate the results from Java Melody. As explained in the Melody documentation [here](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#optional-centralization-server-setup) and let your application register with that service.

Comment: thanks for reply.Is there any other way without centralized collect server setup

Comment: Not AFAIK. Each app collects stats itself, so you need to centralize the storage and dispay. Or ditch java-melody, use the defeault actuators / metrics from Spring Boot and use something like Grafana to aggregate the results.